# Quais as opções de bibliotecas free para geração de PDF em ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Atualmente estou usando o biblioteca selectpdf, mas ela tem algumas restrições na sua versão free, gostaria de saber outras opções que eu possa usar.

Comment: as vezes que precisei gerar PDF eu criei um relatório com o ReportViewer e usei os próprios métodos ele para gerar o PDF.

Comment: Agora sim. Vou pesquisar um pouco e escrever uma resposta.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque as respostas serão baseadas em links apenas, o que pode invalidar as respostas a qualquer momento. Sem falar que as respostas serão baseadas nas opiniões do autor da resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [RazorPDF2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorPDF2/) (minha autoria);
- [MvcRazorToPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcRazorToPdf/);
- [PdfSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfSharp);
- [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa);
- [IronPdf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPdf/) (pago);
- [Spire.PDF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/);

Lembrando que os dois primeiros são apenas envelopes do [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/), que tem licença Affero (livre para desenvolver, paga se o sistema for um SaaS).